# Stopping a thread from outside

Tags: python, multithreading

I am working on a project, and I run a thread. Inside this thread, there is a blocking function (`win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW`) that doesn't allow me to close the thread from within. I tried a few things like closing the tread by getting its id but nothing seems to work:

1. `threading.get_ident()` - crashes when I try to close the thread with that id.
2. `os.getpid()` - closes the entire project and not just the thread itself.

Is there a way to close the thread from the outside? Thanks in advance.

```py
import os
import win32file
import win32con
import multiprocessing
import psutil
import threading
import queue
from pubsub import pub
import wx
import time


class monitoring:

    @staticmethod
    def monitor(path_to_watch, path):
        q = queue.Queue()
        folderpath = path_to_watch[:path_to_watch.rfind('\\')]
        filename = path_to_watch[path_to_watch.rfind('\\') + 1:]
        tempfilename = f'~${filename}'
        t = threading.Thread(target=monitoring.checkforupdates, args=(q, folderpath,))
        t.start()
        id = q.get()
        while True:
            if not q.empty():
                results = q.get()
                for action, file in results:
                    if action <= 3:
                        if file == filename and action == 3:
                            with open(path_to_watch, 'rb')as f:
                                wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, 'update_file_flag', filename=path, file=f.read())
                        elif file == tempfilename and action == 2:
                            print("temp file closed")
                            # here i need to close the thread
                            os.remove(path_to_watch)
                            print(10)
                            exit()
            else:
                time.sleep(5)

    @staticmethod
    def checkforupdates(q, folderpath):
        ACTIONS = {
            1: "Created",
            2: "Deleted",
            3: "Updated",
        }
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001
        hDir = win32file.CreateFile(
            folderpath,
            FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
            win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
            None,
            win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
            win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
            None
        )
        while True:
            #
            # ReadDirectoryChangesW takes a previously-created
            # handle to a directory, a buffer size for results,
            # a flag to indicate whether to watch subtrees and
            # a filter of what changes to notify.
            #
            # NB Tim Juchcinski reports that he needed to up
            # the buffer size to be sure of picking up all
            # events when a large number of files were
            # deleted at once.
            #
            results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW(
                hDir,
                1024,
                False,
                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
                None,
                None
            )
            q.put(results)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to kill a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread)